# How to stub two level of json data bag in chef spec

Tags: chef-infra, chefspec

I'm trying to write the unit test for chef and stubbing the encrypted data bag as below.
Recipe part

```
variables(car_model: Chef::EncryptedDataBagItem.load('databagname', node.environment, key_name)['cardetails']['car_model'])
```

Doing stub in below pattern

```
Chef::EncryptedDataBagItem.stub(:load).with('databagname', 'test', 'somekey').and_return(
"cardetails": {
  'car_model' => 'abc'
  }
)
```

Getting error as undefined method

### NoMethodError

undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass

### Cookbook Trace:

My data bag structure is

`{
  "id": "databagname",
  "cardetails": {
    "car_model": "ABC",
    "car_engine": "XYZ",
    "car_type": "DEE",
  }
}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It got resolved when i'm using below syntax for stubbing

```
Chef::EncryptedDataBagItem.stub(:load).with('databagname', 'test', 'somekey').and_return(
  "cardetails" => {'car_model' => 'abcasasasasas'}
  )
```

Answer (score 0):

In general you shouldn't be using that API if you can help it. The normal `data_bag_item` API automatically decrypts if needed, and then you could use the normal stub helpers in ChefSpec.